# Get duration from .wav file

Tags: jquery, html, web-applications, jquery-plugins, html5-audio

I am looking for something that will play a wav file on a website BUT I want to highlight a waveform or horizontal bar which will then display selected duration in seconds (HTML text).

For example, 60 seconds wav file:

[image]

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you got any code? What are you using to embed the audio?

Answer (score 0):

I've found this old bookmark for you. You'll find all you need in the examples : http://neutroncreations.com/blog/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-jquery/

It explains how to build the horizontal bar, how to load the file and how to calculate the duration.

Regards ;)